# Need help in JQuery scroll function

Tags: jquery

I am developing a small project and i need a help in JQuery Scroll event.
   I wrote code loading data while scrolling using following code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*.75){
                $('#loadingimage').css({"bottom":"10px", "right":"10px"}).fadeIn('fast');
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../../scroll_load.php",
                    data: "letter="+letter+"&start="+start,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {

                        $('#new_music_videos .appendvideos').append(msg).children(':last').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                        $('#loadingimage').fadeOut('fast');
                    }
                });

            }
            });
```

But data loading while the scroll bar is moving at bottom of the screen only. How can i make it for scroll upto 3/4 of the screen.

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For the updated question:*

```
var loading = false; //stores if we're loading, to prevent "over-loading", I'm hilarious
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //if we're loading, or the scroll wasn't 3/4 of the way down, ignore the event
  if (loading || $(window).scrollTop() < ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*.75) return;

  loading = true; //loading! prevent scroll from loading until we're finished
  $('#loadingimage').css({"bottom":"10px", "right":"10px"}).fadeIn('fast');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../../scroll_load.php",
      data: "letter="+letter+"&start="+start,
      success: function(msg) {
          loading = false; //done loading, a scroll can load more again
          $('#new_music_videos .appendvideos').append(msg).children(':last').hide().fadeIn('slow');
          $('#loadingimage').fadeOut('fast');
      }
  });
});
```

*For previous question:*
You can just check if it's over 3/4 of the way down, rather than equal to the total, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*.75) {
     //rest of code
```

Note that with this, especially on longer pages, it'll now be `true` many times before reaching the bottom, so you'll probably want to set a `loading` boolean flag to prevent loading new content multiple times at once.

Comment: @Nick Craver : Thanks for the tip. But with this so many requests are sending and lot of data is loading. I think loop is running many times

Comment: @KillerFish - see the bottom of the answer :) you probably want a `var loading` outside, a `loading=true` inside the `if` and a `if(loading) return;` *before* the `if`, and only set `loading=false` when you've completed loading new data.

Comment: @Nick sory i didn't read your answer completly .. can u modify my code once ..i'll be thankful u a lot.. i am updating my question.

Comment: @KillerFish - updated answer, I can't test atm, but should work...comment if you have any problems :)